# Get list of all report names

Tags: reporting, metadata-api, c#

I would like to obtain a list of all SalesForce reports under all folders - the ones available by default (ex - All reports under Accounts and Contact Reports folder) and also the custom reports.
At the moment I use the 'MetadataService.listMetadata' (generated from metadata.wsdl) method to obtain the report names but this gives me information only about custom reports. How do I get names of all the reports avaiable.
Here is the existing code

```
 ListMetadataQuery query = new ListMetadataQuery();
 q.type = "ReportFolder";
 FileProperties[] fp = metadataService.listMetadata(new ListMetadataQuery[] { q }, 32);
 if (fp == null)
 {
       return new string[0];
 }

 List<string> reportFiles = new List<string>();
 q.type = "Report";
 foreach (MetadataService.FileProperties p in fp)
 {
     q.folder = p.fullName;
     FileProperties[] rps = metadataService.listMetadata(new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery[] { q }, 32);
      if (rps == null) continue;
      foreach (FileProperties rp in rps)
      {
           reportFiles.Add(rp.fullName);
      }
 }

 return reportFiles.ToArray();
```